# Select Only one row per ID and Date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to do something in SQL and I'm currently confused!

So I have something like this:

```
idEvent   idService   dateCreated
-------   ---------   -----------
1         1           2012-01-01
2         1           2012-02-02
3         2           2012-01-01
4         2           2012-02-02
```

The `idEvent` is auto-incrementing.

What I need to get is the biggest row (ordered by `dateCreated DESC`) for each `idService`.

So I'd need to get this as a result :

```
idEvent
-------
2
4
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a common table expression to apply a "row number" to each idService / dateCreated combination. You didn't specify your table name, so you'll have to fix that.

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT idEvent, idService, dateCreated, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY idService ORDER BY dateCreated DESC)
  FROM dbo.table_something_like_this
)
SELECT idEvent, idService, dateCreated
FROM x
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

very similar to Aaron's really but it's a small variation on the theme. On [FIDDLE HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/86915/4)

```
create table the_table 
(
  idEvent INT,
  idService INT,
  dateCreated DATETIME
)

insert into the_table
values
 ( 1, 1, '01 JAN 2012'),
 ( 2, 1, '02 FEB 2012'),
 ( 3, 2, '01 JAN 2012'),
 ( 4, 2, '02 FEB 2012')

SELECT *
FROM 
     the_table a
    INNER JOIN 
        (
        SELECT 
          idEvent
          , rk = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY idService ORDER BY dateCreated DESC) 
        FROM the_table 
        )b
        ON
        a.idEvent = b.idEvent
        AND b.rk= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Stealing a little of the code from whytheq, I rewrote it to use a group by and a table variable.

```
   DECLARE @the_table TABLE
        (
         idEvent INT
        ,idService INT
        ,dateCreated DATETIME
        )

INSERT  INTO @the_table
VALUES  (1,1,'01 JAN 2012'),
        (2,1,'02 FEB 2012'),
        (3,2,'01 JAN 2012'),
        (4,2,'02 FEB 2012')


SELECT  MAX(idEvent)
FROM    @the_table
GROUP BY idService
```